# Segmenting conditional counts into the same 'virtual' column

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to go from a result set like this:

```
"foo" | "bar" | "baz"
----------------------
 30.0 |  20.0 | 50.0
```

(where "foo", "bar", and "baz" are aliases for various conditional `count()` statements)

to a result set like this:

```
"segment" | "count"
-------------------
  "foo"   |   30.0
  "bar"   |   20.0
  "baz"   |   50.0
```

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT round(count(CASE WHEN posts.deactivated_for IS NULL THEN 1 END) ::DECIMAL / count(*), 4) * 100 AS "Foo",
       round(count(CASE WHEN posts.deactivated_for ILIKE '%Died%' THEN 1 END) ::DECIMAL / count(*), 4) * 100 AS "Bar",
       round(count(CASE WHEN posts.deactivated_for ILIKE '%(#%' THEN 1 END) ::DECIMAL / count(*), 4) * 100 AS "Baz"
FROM posts
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT round(count(CASE WHEN posts.deactivated_for IS NULL THEN 1 END) ::DECIMAL / count(*), 4) * 100 AS "Foo",
             round(count(CASE WHEN posts.deactivated_for ILIKE '%Died%' THEN 1 END) ::DECIMAL / count(*), 4) * 100 AS "Bar",
             round(count(CASE WHEN posts.deactivated_for ILIKE '%(#%' THEN 1 END) ::DECIMAL / count(*), 4) * 100 AS "Baz"
      FROM posts
     ) p, lateral
     (VALUES ('Foo', "Foo"), ('Bar', "Bar"), ('Baz', "Baz")) v(segment, cnt);
```

Alternatively, if the groups are discrete, you can just use `group by`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.deactivated_for IS NULL THEN 'Foo'
             WHEN p.deactivated_for ILIKE '%Died%' THEN 'Bar'
             WHEN p.deactivated_for ILIKE '%(#%' THEN 'Baz'
        END) as segment,
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM posts p
GROUP BY segment
HAVING segment IS NOT NULL;
```